# EventEmitter2 C++ implementation

Tags: c++, eventemitter

I need to port a js library to C++. The library is using [EventEmitter2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eventemitter2) extensively (especially with its wildcard (*) option set). I am not an expert in C++, so I am looking for an equivalent of the EventEmitter2 implementation.

I have found some pub/sub (observer pattern) implementations on github and elsewhere, but they all lack the wildcard functionality.

Is there something similar to npm's EventEmitter2 out there?

Comment: A simple google found this: https://www.rioki.org/2014/12/29/eventemitter-in-c.html

Comment: I saw that one, but it focuses on "int" events and most importantly, doesn't support wildcards like npm's EventEmitter2